# Quarkus SwaggerUI ignores http.root.path if resteasy-reactive path is set

Tags: quarkus

Im using the following config:

```
quarkus.http.root-path=/test-service
quarkus.http.port=${PORT:8080}
quarkus.resteasy-reactive.path=rest
```

SwaggerUI converts this to the following URL in the "try-out" feature:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:8080/rest/v1/test' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'
```

SwaggerUI ignores the http.root.path set in the config.

When im using the `@ApplicationPath("/rest")` annotation instead of `quarkus.resteasy-reactive.path`, everything works just fine. Is this intended or am I missing something?

Using: Quarkus 2.10.2.Final and RestEasy-Reactive

Comment: This sounds like a bug, please open a GitHub issue

Comment: Created an Issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/26870